# I want to perform many tasks in one Edittext

Tags: android

I want to perform many task in one Edittext. Like when I edit the first number in edittext  it store in string value  and edittext may be null after that when I enter 2nd number in same edittext 2nd number may also save in another string. Then after some action perform answer show in Textview.
Please help me out...

Comment: Are you stuck with any part in particular? You should approach what you want to do one step at a time.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. By all means, get help with English, if from automated translation from a language you mastered. While it wasn't my first language, I'm confident that my utter lack of "getting" what you want isn't all my fault.

Comment: Sure, what is your current problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void save_on_cick_listen(){
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
              if(save == 0){
                  // save first string
                  editText.getText().clear(); //or you can use editText.setText("");
                  save+;
              } else if (save == 1){
                  // save second string
                  editText.getText().clear(); //or you can use editText.setText("");
                  save+;
              }  
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir have a nice day

Comment: If this helped you please click the check mark to accept my answer